# Quiero imprimir un string random de mi Array

Tags: array, random, c++.net

No me deja imprimir un string random de mi lista

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    srand(time(0));
    std::string word[] = {"black","metal"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int ra = rand() % 2;
        MessageBox::Show("Random: " + word[ra]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Esto no es C++.

Comment: Esto es C++.NET. La etiqueta C++ no se debe utilizar con la versión .NET

Comment: Si rand() te da un valor deciml aleatorio entre 0.0 y 1.0 (es lo más habitual) entonces en lugar de % 2 necesitarás * 2. Es decir, multiplicar rand() por el tamaño del Array (en este caso es 2).

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos me sirvió mucho